# Is it safe to reuse my seed to create a different wallet that supports Bitcoin?

Tags: wallets

I created a wallet for Ether using MyEtherWallet. I want to store Bitcoin now, but MyEtherWallet does not support it.

Since I prefer not having to remember two different seed-phrases, I was thinking of just reusing the 12 word seed-phrase of MyEtherWallet to create a new wallet on one that does support Bitcoin, for example Electrum (I know that Electrum doesn't use the standard BI39 protocol).

I can't think of any problem with doing this, but I'm kind of new to this, so maybe there's something I haven't thought of.

Is there something I'm missing here? Is doing this considered unsafe?

For what it's worth, for the time being and for the foreseable future, I do not plan to actually use my wallet to spend any crypto, only to accumulate. My seed-phrase was generated on an old laptop that will never be connected to the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically, the BIP39 phrase is a readable representation of a "seed", which can be used to create add private keys according to a "derivation path".  for BTC that would be `m/44’/0’/0’/0/0` (legacy) and for segwit: `m/84’/0’/0’/0/0`.  one seed can create many private keys according to the path.  so if you already have a key you use for Ethereum, yes, you can create one for BTC. google derivation paths for a better understanding

Comment: I know the basics about derivation paths and that's why I presumed there should be nothing wrong with taking the same seed, but I wanted to be sure I wasn't missing anything. Thanks.

Comment: no worries.  glad I was of help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is safe.

This is a very cool tool you can use for that: https://iancoleman.io/bip39/.